# Dynamically changing properties of a Storyboard (created in XAML) in the C# code-behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I admit I'm new to Silverlight, but you have to start somewhere.

Here's my problem:  I have XAML code which creates a Canvas to be used on my web page.  I dynamiclly (in the code behind) create 24 smaller canvas objects (called tiles) and can correctly position and move these tiles inside the larger canvas.  I want to now animate the movement of the tiles rather than have them just "jump" from one location to the next.  Inside the XAML I created a Storyboard and a DoubleAnimation for one of the tiles.  Clicking on the specific tile named in the DoubleAnimation/Storyboard produces the correct animation.  Now I want to be able to change the properties of the animation in the XAML dynamically by the code in the code-behind.  Specifically, I want to change the "From", "To", "Storyboard.TargetName", and "Storyboard.TargetProperty" values.  This would allow me to use the single animation to control the movement of all 24 tiles (one at a time).  Below is the XAML and below that is the code I've been attempting to get to work correctly.

### XAML

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Height="700" Width="1405">
    <Image Source="bkcolor.png" Canvas.Left="600" Height="500" Width="500" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Top="100"></Image>
    <Canvas x:Name="myContainer" Canvas.Left = "50" Canvas.Top="100">
        <!---->
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="MoveTileAnimation">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="myDoubleAnimation"
                    From="400" To="300" 
                    Duration="00:00:1" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Tile23"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <PowerEase Power="3" EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <!---->
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

### C# Code in Code Behind

```
private void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
    // New location is specified by nx, ny
    int nx = 200;
    int ny = 300;

    // Old Location
    int ox = 200;
    int oy = 200;

    // "Tile Moves Up" -- Other case removed for clarity

    //----------------------------------------------
    // Code below is known to work correctly
    //----------------------------------------------
    // Set the "To" and "From" properties
    myDoubleAnimation.From = Convert.ToDouble(oy);
    myDoubleAnimation.To = Convert.ToDouble(ny);


    //----------------------------------------------
    // Code below does not function correctly
    //----------------------------------------------
    MoveTileAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, c.Name);  // c.Name is the
                                                                    // name of the tile
                                                                    // that was clicked
    MoveTileAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty)); // Need to switch between Top and Left
    //----------------------------------------------


    MoveTileAnimation.Begin(); // This works if the TargetNameProperty in
                               // the XAML matches the Tile Name

    //----------------------------------------------
    // Code below is known to work correctly
    //----------------------------------------------
    // Move the Tile to its new position
    tileCanvas[nCanvasID].SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(ny));
    tileCanvas[nCanvasID].SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(nx));
}
```

I don't want to have to create 96 storyboards to be able to move 24 tiles in each of 4 directions.  If I can get changing the "TargetNameProperty" working, that reduces to 4 storyboards.  If I can also get changing the "TargetPropertyProperty" working, I'm done to a single storyboard.

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link points to an article with code for reusable storyboards.   It's an old article, but still applies today - maybe these classes will help you.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24543/Creating-and-Reusing-Dynamic-Animations-in-Silverl

Comment: Thanks.  It was the storyboard.stop and storyboard.begin I was missing.